# List directories of different location in fish tab-completion

Tags: fish, tab-completion

I would like to create a fish function that acts as a shortcut into a directory.

The function looks like this:

```
function mydir -d "Navigate to mydir and its subdirectories from anywhere"
    cd $HOME/some/path/mydir/$argv
end
```

The function works well, but I would like to add tab-completion. I currently have this for tab-completion:

```
complete --no-files --exclusive --command mydir --arguments "(__fish_complete_directories)"
```

The problem is that this will tab-complete to the directories in the current working directory. **I would instead like it to tab-complete to the directories in `$HOME/some/path/mydir/`.** I cannot find an example or flag in the documentation that would help me do this.

I do not know fish very well, but I thought one way to do this would be to manually loop over those directories and add them as options, but it doesn't feel right and I am struggling with that implementation anyway.

Comment: You might also want to give `z` a try. I'm using it for a long time now and it works like a charm. The more you use it, the better its predictions are:
https://github.com/jethrokuan/z

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, your "looping over those directories" seems like the most "fish-like" way to me, but given that someone has already gone through the trouble of creating and debugging the existing `__fish_complete_directories` ([Github link](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/share/functions/__fish_complete_directories.fish)), I think I'd just use it as a starting point for your own completion function.

It seems to me that you could just add a `pushd $HOME/some/path/mydir` before the "non-existent command hack" and then `popd` at the end.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I appreciate the pointer. I'll git that a try.

Comment: `pushd` and `popd` worked like a charm. Thank you.